# How to change the size of the footnotes for the whole document

Tags: footnotes, fontsize

I am using the following function to insert footnotes in the page:

```latex
\footnote{ some text }
```

Can I define the footnotes font size for the entire document?

Comment: \let\foonotesize=\small will do it, but \footnotesize is sometimes used for things other than footnotes.

Comment: There is also `\patch{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}{}{PATCH  FAILED}` from the etoolkit package.

Comment: It works, thanks. Btw, there is a typo "foonotesize" instead of "footnotesize" :)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can I specify the font size instead of (small/tiny/...)?

Comment: Not easily. You need a switch version (\bfseries instead of \textbf} and you may need to add a new font.

Answer (score 2):

With the `memoir` class (enhanced version of the `book` and `report` classes):

```
\documentclass%[...]
                    {memoir}

\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\itshape\large}
```

to get the footnotes printed in a `\large` italic font (but choose something better than this).